# Paste special required in macro transferring data between sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro set up which transfers selected rows to Sheet2 to pass information to another department.

This is a shared spreadsheet and I'm having issues with the macro overwriting conditional formatting on Sheet2 when passed over.

Would anyone be able to help with altering the macro below to paste values only which I hope will not overwrite any conditional formatting already applied on Sheet 2.

```
Sub Pass_to_xDepartment()

Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo Whoops

'Declare variables
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim WSheet As Variant
Dim DTable As Variant
Dim Sendrng As Range
Dim sht3 As Worksheet

'MsgBox when passing over work
If MsgBox("Do you want to pass the selected work to xDepartment?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please ensure selected work is complete." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This will generate an automatic email to xDepartment.", vbYesNo, "Pass to xDepartment") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

For Each WSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        If WSheet.FilterMode Then
            WSheet.ShowAllData
        End If
    End If
    For Each DTable In WSheet.ListObjects
        If DTable.ShowAutoFilter Then
            DTable.Range.AutoFilter
            DTable.Range.AutoFilter
        End If
    Next DTable
Next WSheet

'Set variables
Set sht1 = Sheets("yDepartment")
Set sht2 = Sheets("xDepartment")

'Move row to destination sheet & Delete source row
lastRow = sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Select Entire Row.Resize(ColumnSize:=12)
Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Selection.Parent.Columns("N")).Value = Date

With Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, Selection.Parent.Range("A:N"))
    .Copy Destination:=sht2.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
    lastRow2 = sht2.Range("A" & sht2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    .EntireRow.Delete
End With

On Error Resume Next
Set sht3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("temp")
On Error GoTo 0
If sht3 Is Nothing Then
    Set sht3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
    sht3.Name = "temp"
Else
    sht3.UsedRange.Clear
End If
'Note: if the selection is one cell it will send the whole worksheet
Set Sendrng = sht2.Range("A" & (lastRow + 1) & ":N" & lastRow2)
Sendrng.Copy Destination:=sht3.Range("A1")

 On Error GoTo StopMacro

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Create the mail and send it
sht3.Activate
lastRow2 = sht3.Range("A" & sht3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set Sendrng = sht3.Range("A1:N" & lastRow2)

With Sendrng

    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
    With .Parent.MailEnvelope

        ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
        ' some header text to the email body.
        .Introduction = "Dear xDepartment," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "The following work has been completed." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please see the shared spreadsheet for further details." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Kind regards," & vbNewLine & "yDepartment" & vbNewLine

        With .Item
            .To = "email"
            .CC = "email"
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "New work passed over from yDepartment"
            .Send
        End With

    End With
End With

StopMacro:

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False
Worksheets("yDepartment").Activate
MsgBox ("Tours have been passed to xDepartment.")

Whoops:
 Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `.Copy Destination:=…` split it into two lines. First just `.Copy`, and second `Range("destination").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`. Do this with all copy actions in your code.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks for your help!